# Using a Loop To Search Only Logs In A Time Window

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I'm trying to find a pattern "INFO: Server startup in" for last 5 mins in a log file.

Here is the line from which I'm trying to find the pattern: "INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/07/09 00:11:29.077 | INFO: Server startup in 221008 ms"

The pattern is coming, but I need to shorten the code or create a loop for it.

I tried to create a loop, but it is not working. Here is my code without loops, which is working:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Written by Ashutosh
#We will declare variables with date and time of last 5 mins.
touch /tmp/a.txt;
ldt=$(date +"%Y%m%d");
cdt=$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M");
odtm5=$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" --date "-5 min");
odtm4=$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" --date "-4 min");
odtm3=$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" --date "-3 min");
odtm2=$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" --date "-2 min");
odtm1=$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" --date "-1 min");

## Finding the pattern and storing it in a file
grep -e "$odtm1" -e "$cdt" -e "$odtm2" -e "$odtm3" -e "$odtm4" -e 
"$odtm5" /some/log/path/console-$ldt.log 
> /tmp/a.txt;
out=$(grep 'INFO: Server startup in' /tmp/a.txt);
echo "$out" 

## remove the file that contains the pattern
rm /tmp/a.txt;
```

I have tried to use sed also, but date function is not working with it.
Can someone please give me the new changed script with loops?

Comment: Does performance matter? Is the date at the front of each line of the log? What's the format? To be clear, `grep` will read all the way from the front of the log, so it's much slower than finding the point 5 minutes ago via bisecting the file and reading forward only from there.

Comment: BTW, you're either missing some line continuation characters (backslashes), or you have some extra newlines in this code.

Comment: Performance doesn't matter, Yes the date is at front of each line. Format can be found by seeing the variables. But my above script is working just fine, I want a loop for this script. Here is the exact pattern "INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/07/09 00:11:29.077 | INFO: Server startup in 221008 ms"

Comment: That's not "at the front" -- that means `INFO | jvm 1 | main |` is at the front. If that data's constant, no issue. If not, then we can't just rely on a straight bisect.

Comment: What do you mean, "want a loop"? My answer **does** loop -- `awk` implicitly loops over each line of its input.

Comment: can we loop the '-5 min'? I want to give a random number to it, you are using 5 line s for it as of now.

Comment: I already edited that change in. Maybe you need to reload?

Comment: (that said, it'd be saner to use GNU awk's support for date/time parsing... if, again, we're going to stick with awk and not do something smarter that can bisect the file to find the start point without needing to read all the way from the top).

Comment: Insofar as you don't want to do this in the fastest possible way (which others asking about searching for the last N minutes presumably will -- especially if they're dealing with log files that grow into the tens or hundreds of MB, as is typically the case), I'm adopting the title to more narrowly describe your intent (of adopting existing code to use a loop).

Comment: This log generates 10 lines per second. I don't think this will be an issue, will test it in dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like all you need is:

```
awk -v start="$(date +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M' --date '-5 min')" -F'[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*' '
    ($4>=start) && /INFO: Server startup in/
' file
```

No explicit loops or multiple calls to `date` required.

Comment: Yup. The OP hadn't told us their log format when I wrote my answer, so I didn't know that `$4` was available to inspect; at that point, the spec that we had was just that the date existed somewhere in the string -- but it's unsafe to assume that no log messages ever contain dates in the future as content in other positions.

Comment: This Works like a charm, but what does the $4 variable do @Ed Morton?

Comment: You said your input looked like `INFO | jvm 1 | main | 2018/07/09 00:11:29.077 | INFO: Server startup in 221008 ms` so that's 5 fields separated by `|`s and the 4th field (`$4`) is the one containing the date.

Answer (score 4):

Adopting your original logic:

```
time_re='('
for ((count=5; count>0; count--)); do
  time_re+="$(date +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M' --date "-$count min")|"
done
time_re+="$(date +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'))"

ldt=$(date +'%Y%m%d')

awk -v time_re="$time_re" '
  $0 ~ time_re && /INFO: Server startup in/ { print $0 }
' "/some/log/path/console-$ldt.log"
```

Performance enhancements are certainly possible -- this could be made much faster by bisecting the log for the start time -- but the above addresses the explicit question (about using a loop to generate the time window). Note that it *will* get unwieldy -- you wouldn't want to use this to search for the last day, for example, as the regex would become utterly unreasonable.

Comment: Let me try it. I will let you know soon.

Comment: This works like a charm, but can we print the output of the pattern also?

Comment: Just take out the `count` parts, and change the `count = count + 1` to `print`, if that's what you want.

Comment: It is printing the date only, not the complete pattern for which it found it.

Comment: I'd need so see the code exactly as adopted. You might `print $0`, to refer explicitly to the full line.

Comment: Got an error:    
`line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
`line 12: `' "/tmp/console-$ldt.log")'`

Comment: That's left over from when the whole thing was in a command substitution (because I thought you wanted the count, not the actual lines). Just delete the `)` character.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `bash` script that does the job (thanks to Charles for its improvement):

```
#!/bin/bash
limit=$(date -d '5 minutes ago' +%s)
today_logs="/some/log/path/console-$(date +'%Y%m%d').log"
yesterday_logs="/some/log/path/console-$(date +'%Y%m%d' -d yesterday).log"

tac "$today_logs" "$yesterday_logs" \
| while IFS='|' read -r prio jvm app date log; do
    [ $(date -d "$date" +%s) -lt "$limit" ] && break
    echo "|$jvm|$prio|$app|$date|$log"
done \
| grep -F 'INFO: Server startup in' \
| tac
```

It has the following advantages over your original script:

- optimized: it parses log lines starting from the more recent ones and stops at the first line encountered that is more than 5 min old. At 23:59, no need to parse log lines from 0:00 to 23:53
- arbitrary time window: you can replace "5 minutes" with "18 hours" and it will still work. A time window of more than one day needs adaptation since each day has it own log file
- works correctly when day changes: at 0:00 the original script will never parse the log lines from 23:55:00 to 23:59:59

Mixing the above code with [Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51250452/7233423), you get:

```
#!/bin/bash
limit=$(date -d '5 minutes ago' +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
today_logs="/some/log/path/console-$(date +'%Y%m%d').log"
yesterday_logs="/some/log/path/console-$(date +'%Y%m%d' -d yesterday).log"

tac "$today_logs" "$yesterday_logs" \
| awk -v stop="$limit" -F'[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*' '
    ($4 < stop) { exit }
    /INFO: Server startup in/
' \
| tac
```

Comment: Let me try the script. Will let you know soon if it works or not?

Comment: Please do. And try the second script too.

Comment: Running `date=$(cut ...)` once per line (on a file that isn't known to be short -- even though we're reading from the end, we don't know how many hundreds of lines are in that five minutes) is **insanely** slow, and there's no reason to do it. `while IFS='|' read -r log_level jvm_name app date rest; do` will populate the first four fields in variables named `log_level`, `jvm_name`, `app` and `date`, and everything after the date in the variable named `rest`. You can thus `echo "${log_level}|${jvm_name}|${app}|${date}|${rest}"` to reproduce the original line in full afterwards.

Comment: I also would advise against relying on `$REPLY` in general -- that's a bashism, whereas if you specify an explicit destination variable name to `read` your code is portable.

Comment: (Keep in mind that heredocs and herestrings create temporary files, so `date=$(cut -d'|' -f4 <<<"$REPLY")` is (1) forking off a subshell, (2) creating a temporary file, (3) writing your current line into that file, (4) opening the file as stdin, (5) creating a FIFO pair, (6) connecting stdout from cut to that FIFO, (7) connecting stdin to the cut to the temporary file, (8) reading the FIFO to its end, (9) calling waitpid to collect cut's exit status; that's a lot of overhead, vs using bash's built-in string manipulation tools).

Comment: True for your first comment, thanks. As for your second one, there is no reason not to rely on bashisms when bash is used. As for your third one, you are right again that it isn't by far the most efficient way, but you said it already in comment #1. I will amend my first code but you should really focus on the second code which you'll probably appreciate more as it is not only efficient but fixes a number of flaws that were in the original post, and without resorting to bisection.

Comment: Why pay all the costs involved in running `date` in a subshell to convert to seconds when the date format in use is amenable to a native string comparison? `[[ $date < $limit ]]` after changing the assignment of `limit` to `limit=$(date -d '5 minutes ago' '+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')` is far faster. I do indeed appreciate the second example, and wonder why you're keeping the other branch at all.

Comment: For historical reasons, probably for the same reason you keep your answer.

Comment: @xhienne Thanks both the script works just fine! Btw what is `tac` used for? Is it like `sed`?

Comment: @Ashutosh, `tac` reverses a file, reading from bottom to top. Much more efficient to only read from than the bottom (if content near the bottom is all you're looking for) than to read content up to and discard it. Doing that twice means that the content you keep come out in proper order.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are Right!, will keep in mind. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks @Charles for the explanation. Somehow I missed Ashutosh's question.